# How does HOSTNAME_COMMAND work on wurstmeister/kafka-docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to get wurstmeister/kafka-docker working in swarm mode on docker-machine, so far, without much luck.  However, I'm not sure I understand how the HOSTNAME_COMMAND works. Here's the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

So, I gather that HOSTNAME_COMMAND gets the host name, but for the _ syntax: _{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}

Is this part of docker-compose? Kafka? or is this an add-on by wurstmeister?
And am I correct in assuming that it gets evaluated for each of the nodes participating in the swarm?  I couldn't find any documentation that explains where this comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "an addon" in the [wurstmeister Dockerfile CMD script](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L44).

The value is evaluated for each Docker service, and called within the container at start, which just calls `eval` on that command.

https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/start-kafka.sh#L52-L63

The `_{NAME}` syntax isn't significant other than a pattern to do string replacement within the bash script on that entire value

Comment: I see that now, (and am wondering how I missed it in the first place).  Thanks!  Unfortunately, that doesn't give me any clues why I can't connect. I have some more digging to do, I guess.